# Business Week Group in SQL (instead of calendar week)

Tags: sql-server, date, calendar, weekend

My requirement is that I want to find `business-week-ending` (not the calender week) given a `DATE` column from the sales table in MSSQL.

Using different techniques I was able to find the [Calender] week-endings (and week-starting) dates corresponding to `DATE` in the table.

Since our business week ends on Wednesday [DOW 3 or 4 depending when the week started], I tried to deduct number of days from the week ending dates to pull it back to Wednesday. The idea did work pretty good with a flaw. Works fine as long as the `Date` in the table is greater than DOW 3 or 4. Any suggestion?

```
SELECT DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, Recons_Sales_Details.Recons_Date), 0) + 2
```

Comment: Can you please post your code that you have tried?

Comment: Your code uses Monday - Sunday week because day zero (1.1.1900) was Monday. You can change that by changing the both 0s to some other date, which is for example Thursday

Comment: @JamesZ:  20130102 is Wed. this code does ends the week on Wednesday. but at the same time it pusshes back 20150801 back to weekending 7/29.  DateAdd(week,
  DateDiff(week, '2013-01-02', Recons_Sales_Details.Recons_Date), '2013-01-02'),

Comment: Sorry, you'll of course need to use days / 7, DateAdd(week, DateDiff(day, '2013-01-03', Recons_Sales_Details.Recons_Date) / 7, '2013-01-03')

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) to do this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 4  --4 is Thursday week start
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e5e4/5/0)

Comment: **DATEFIRST** was the very first appealing option I liked the most, however my limitation with this option is that this production (cloud) server has multiple clients with different business industries and geography. And as far as I understand DATEFIRST will change the server-calendar.

Comment: @Honda I am not sure if `DATEFIRST` actually changes anything else but the adhoc query that you run. Just like `SET NO COUNT ON`, I believe it only applies to a specific session/transaction.